# We need to fill in all the NA spots with formulas without any lm functions or predict functions in R

Tags: r

We need to fill in all the NA spots with formulas without any lm functions or predict functions in R Please help! can't figure it out without lm or predict, I did the x_bar, y_bar, and n however the other ones are much more challenging. This is used in R studio but could be in R as well.

```css
statsslr = function(x, y){
  
  x_bar = mean(x)
  y_bar = mean(y)
  n = length(x)

  #fit the model
  beta1_hat = NA
  beta0_hat = NA

  #find fitted values and residuals for the n inputs in vector x
  yhat = NA         #this is a vector of length n
  residuals = NA    #this is a vector of length n
  
  SSE = NA
  SST = NA
  SSxx = NA
  
  #calculate measures of fit
  s = NA
  Rsq = NA
  
  #calculate standard errors
  beta0_SE = NA
  beta1_SE = NA
  
  #calculate t-scores
  beta0_tscore = NA
  beta1_tscore = NA
  
  #calculate p-values
  beta0_pvalue = NA
  beta1_pvalue = NA
  
  #DON'T CHANGE
  #Plotting lines with software can be done by plotting points.  Think about it... the screen only has so many pixels, so isn't it the same thing?
  #We'll plot the confidence bands by finding their values at 1000 particular x-values over the range of the x data
  xp = seq(min(x), max(x), length=1000)
  
  #Calculate 95% confidence and prediction intervals for the 1000 particular x-values in xp
  #Everything calculated in this block is for each value in xp, so the results are vectors of length 1000
  yp = NA
  SE_yp_at_xp = NA
  SE_Ey_at_xp = NA
  CI_yp_upper = yp + qt(NA, NA)*SE_yp_at_xp   #little help :)
  CI_yp_lower = NA
  CI_Ey_upper = NA
  CI_Ey_lower = NA

  #DON'T CHANGE (unless you want to customize)
  options(digits=4)
  x_name = deparse(substitute(x))
  y_name = deparse(substitute(y))
  plot(x, y, xlab=paste("x = ", x_name), ylab=paste("y = ", y_name))
  abline(beta0_hat, beta1_hat, lwd=2)
  lines(xp, CI_yp_upper, col="red", lty=2, lwd=1.5)
  lines(xp, CI_yp_lower, col="red", lty=2, lwd=1.5)
  lines(xp, CI_Ey_upper, col="blue", lty=2, lwd=1.5)
  lines(xp, CI_Ey_lower, col="blue", lty=2, lwd=1.5)

  #FIX ALL THE MISTAKES
  cat("\nSimple Least Squares with x = ", y_name, "and y =", x_name,"\n\n")
  cat("The sample regression equation is \n\n\t y = ", beta0_hat, "+", beta1_SE, "* x\n\n")
  cat("Intercept:  SE      =", beta0_SE, "\n\t    t-score =", beta0_hat, "\n\t    P(>|t|) =", 1-beta0_pvalue, "\n\n")
  cat("Slope:\t    SE      =", beta0_SE, "\n\t    t-score =", beta1_tscore, "\n\t    P(>|t|) =", 1-beta1_pvalue, "\n\n")
  cat("Residual Standard Error is s = ", Rsq, "on", n, "degrees of freedom")
  cat("\nCoefficient of Determination is R^2 =", sqrt(Rsq), "\n\n")

  options(digits=7)

}
```

Comment: There is no solution you can get that is specific to RStudio and not applicable to R: the former is *just* the development environment (gui interface), and it is wrapping around the R interpreter/language. Please only use the [tag:rstudio] for questions having to do with the interface itself, not the R programming language.

Comment: Sara, this question is really about the theory behind linear regression, not about any programming questions per se. (That is, you've not communicated any errors, warnings, or much personal code for that matter.) As such, I'm voting to migrate it to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), where the questions are more focused on the theory and math. Good luck.

Comment: In general you will find participants are reluctant to answer homework questions unless it involves small focused parts of questions which are holding you back.  What you can do is some googling to find the formulas.  Then convert these formulas to R and plug them in as required.  Then run your function and compare the results to the output from `summary(lm(...))` and `predict(lm(...), ...)` to ensure that you got them right.  If you still have problems with one or two of them you might get an answer if you reduce the problem to just those with problems and show formula and code you attempted.